# WordPress single page rewrite rule / Adding custom page slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slug

I would like to change this page:

```
mysite.com/?ct_additional_features=hilltop&search-listings=true
```

to look like this:

```
mysite.com/test
```

Below is what I added to my `htaccess`: (above the WP main rewrite rules)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) index.php/?ct_additional_features=hilltop&search-listings=true [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ /?ct_additional_features=hilltop&search-listings=true [L]
```

It will leave you with `mysite.com/test`

Comment: It's working now, however the page title still showing default for 401 "Nothing found ...". Any idea how can I change that also?